# How to transfer menu between pages in Visual Studio C# project

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm new to C#, and am trying to make a multi-page program with a GUI in Visual Studio. Ideally, I'd like to create some kind of nav-bar with menu options like "Home", "FAQ", "Register", etc. Is it necessary for me to re-create this structure for each distinct page? Is there a way to transfer some kind of menu between pages - so for example, the "Home" and "FAQ" pages both display the navigational menu?

Any help/info would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: If by "multi-page program" you mean Asp.Net web application/website then look up "master pages" - that's exactly what You're looking for.

Comment: Any technology has its own way to handle menus. What tech are you using here? WinForms, ASP.NET please explain.

Comment: Apologies - I'm doing it through Windows Forms.

Comment: Use MDI form for the case of Windows Forms